# Jekyll serve error - jekyll 3.2.1 Error: File exists @ syserr_fail2_in

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I'm attempting to migrate a Jekyll site over to my local machine and was doing ok but I've run into an error I am struggling to find much information regarding. I am pretty new to the whole Jekyll thing so any help is much appreciated.

When I run `bundle exec jekyll serve` I get the following error:

```
$ bundle exec jekyll serve
Configuration file: /home/Documents/devsite/websites/marketing/_config.yml
Source: /home/Documents/devsite/websites/marketing
Destination: /home/Documents/devsite/websites/marketing/_site
Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
  Generating... 
Building site for default language: "en-gb" to: /home/Documents/devsite/websites/marketing/_site
jekyll 3.2.1 | Error:  File exists @ syserr_fail2_in - /home/Documents/devsite/websites/marketing/_site/favicon.ico
```

I'm unsure as to what this error relates to so I'm a little unsure as to where to go next. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Apparently, you're using an i18n plugin that doesn't work with Jekyll 3.2. A code repository url can be useful to help debugging.

Comment: I'm using bundler, so does that not mean it should have installed compatible plugins? Any idea how I find out which plugin is the i18n? I've not used a code repository url, I'll look into that. Thanks for your help.