# jekyll serve throws an error on Heroku

Tags: heroku, jekyll

I am trying to run my jekyll site using `jekyll serve` but it fails. Below is a list of variations of the command I have tried:

`bundle exec jekyll  serve --port $PORT --host 0.0.0.0`

`bundle exec jekyll serve`

`jekyll serve --port $PORT --host 0.0.0.0`

`jekyll serve`

For all of the above commands it fails and gives me the following error message on my heroku app:

**jekyll 3.7.0 | Error:  File exists @ syserr_fail2_in - /app/_site/bin/erb**

Please can you help. My problem is a little different from this post:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38945794/jekyll-serve-error-jekyll-3-2-1-error-file-exists-syserr-fail2-in)

I have tried the following versions of ruby:

1. 2.1.9
2. 2.2.9
3. 2.3.5
4. 2.4.3

See my config below:

---

**config.ru**

```
require 'rack/jekyll'
run Rack::Jekyll.new
```

---

**Rakefile**

```
namespace :assets do
  task :precompile do
    sh 'bundle exec jekyll build'
  end
end
```

---

**Procfile**

```
web: bundle exec jekyll serve --port $PORT --host 0.0.0.0
```

---

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gemspec
ruby '2.4.3'
gem 'jekyll'
gem 'rack-jekyll'
gem 'rake'
```

---

**_config.yml**

```
title: title
description: description
google_analytics:
theme: jekyll-theme-dinky
jekyll_auth:
      ssl: true
gems: ['kramdown']
exclude: ['config.ru', 'Gemfile', 'Gemfile.lock', 'vendor', 'Procfile', 
'Rakefile']
```

---

I am running my site locally with the same version of ruby, rubygems, bunlder and jekyll without this issue.

If I run this using puma it works but then my permanlinks dont work. I want to run this using jekyll serve

Please can someone help.

---

Herewith the output for `jekyll serve --trace`:

```
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.9/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1371:in `symlink': File exists @ sys_fail2 - /app/_site/bin/erb (Errno::EEXIST)
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.9/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1371:in `copy'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.9/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:472:in `block in copy_entry'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.9/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1498:in `call'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.9/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1498:in `wrap_traverse'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.9/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:469:in `copy_entry'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.7.0/lib/jekyll/static_file.rb:154:in `copy_file'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.7.0/lib/jekyll/static_file.rb:100:in `write'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.7.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:208:in `block in write'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.7.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:329:in `block (2 levels) in each_site_file'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.7.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:328:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.7.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:328:in `block in each_site_file'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.7.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:327:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.7.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:327:in `each_site_file'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.7.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:207:in `write'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.7.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:75:in `process'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.7.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:28:in `process_site'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.7.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:65:in `build'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.7.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:36:in `process'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.7.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `block in start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.7.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.7.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.7.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:75:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `call'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.7.0/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/bin/jekyll:17:in `load'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/bin/jekyll:17:in `<main>'
```

Comment: what is your configuration setting for `exclude:` in your `_config.yml`?

Comment: Hi @ashmaroli, I have updated the above to include my `_config.yml` file

Comment: okay.. can you please post the entire error message that's output when you run `bundle exec jekyll serve --trace`..

Comment: Hi @ashmaroli I have added the content of the output above

Comment: @ClintonShaneWright Did you get solution to this?

Comment: Hi @Shweta, I have not found a solution and I would like to ask for help please.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be because of a symlinked `static_file` that is attempting to write to `_site/bin/erb` after a `_site/bin/erb` has already been written..

Wonder why it doesn't causes similar error while building locally..
The `app/bin` has no role in a static website.. so you can tell Jekyll to ignore that directory by adding it to your `exclude:` array..

Answer (score 0):

After trying a dozen or so things, I took a flyer on downgrading Jekyll to an earlier version. Voila! Sorry - I haven't done any root cause analysis or made an attempt to get it working with the current version.

Jekyll entry in my Gemfile:

```html
gem 'jekyll', '3.0.0'
```