# Unable to deploy Jekyll site to Heroku: Errno::EEXIST related error

Tags: ruby, heroku, jekyll

I'm trying to deploy my Jekyll blog site(code [here](https://github.com/boddhisattva/mohnishjadwani.com)) to Heroku but it currently crashes with the below error. I'm running the app on Ruby 2.7.3 and using Jekyll 4.2.2

```
 State changed from crashed to starting
2022-08-20T04:39:34.291514+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `jekyll serve -P 17944 --no-watch --host 0.0.0.0 --trace`
2022-08-20T04:39:34.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-08-20T04:39:37.033563+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-08-20T04:39:36.527289+00:00 app[web.1]: Configuration file: /app/_config.yml
2022-08-20T04:39:36.539645+00:00 app[web.1]: Source: /app
2022-08-20T04:39:36.539652+00:00 app[web.1]: Destination: /app/_site
2022-08-20T04:39:36.539669+00:00 app[web.1]: Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
2022-08-20T04:39:36.539683+00:00 app[web.1]: Generating...
2022-08-20T04:39:36.607625+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1390:in `symlink': File exists @ syserr_fail2_in - /app/_site/bin/erb (Errno::EEXIST)
2022-08-20T04:39:36.607654+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1390:in `copy'
2022-08-20T04:39:36.607674+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:497:in `block in copy_entry'
2022-08-20T04:39:36.607687+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:1513:in `wrap_traverse'
2022-08-20T04:39:36.607699+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:494:in `copy_entry'
2022-08-20T04:39:36.607716+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/static_file.rb:200:in `copy_file'
2022-08-20T04:39:36.607729+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/static_file.rb:110:in `write'
2022-08-20T04:39:36.607741+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:231:in `block in write'
2022-08-20T04:39:36.607761+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:358:in `block (2 levels) in each_site_file'
2022-08-20T04:39:36.607773+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:357:in `each'
2022-08-20T04:39:36.607786+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:357:in `block in each_site_file'
2022-08-20T04:39:36.607800+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:356:in `each'
2022-08-20T04:39:36.607813+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:356:in `each_site_file'
2022-08-20T04:39:36.607826+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:230:in `write'
2022-08-20T04:39:36.607840+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/site.rb:82:in `process'
2022-08-20T04:39:36.607852+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/command.rb:28:in `process_site'
2022-08-20T04:39:36.607864+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:65:in `build'
2022-08-20T04:39:36.607877+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:36:in `process'
2022-08-20T04:39:36.607890+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `block in process_with_graceful_fail'
2022-08-20T04:39:36.607903+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `each'
2022-08-20T04:39:36.607915+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `process_with_graceful_fail'
2022-08-20T04:39:36.607932+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
2022-08-20T04:39:36.607945+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `block in execute'
2022-08-20T04:39:36.607957+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `each'
2022-08-20T04:39:36.607970+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `execute'
2022-08-20T04:39:36.607983+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/program.rb:44:in `go'
2022-08-20T04:39:36.607995+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary.rb:21:in `program'
2022-08-20T04:39:36.608007+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.2/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
2022-08-20T04:39:36.608025+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/bin/jekyll:29:in `load'
2022-08-20T04:39:36.608039+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/bin/jekyll:29:in `<main>'
2022-08-20T04:39:36.792696+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

I'm not sure how do I solve for the `symlink': File exists @ syserr_fail2_in - /app/_site/bin/erb (Errno::EEXIST)` related error. I tried adding a trace in the jekyll run command [here](https://github.com/boddhisattva/mohnishjadwani.com/blob/main/Procfile#L1) but it still doesn't seem to help. The app deploys successfully on localhost without any errors via `bundle exec jekyll serve`.

The [Jekyll on Heroku blog](https://blog.heroku.com/jekyll-on-heroku) feels outdated. I also followed one of the more recent setting up Jekyll on heroku blogs [here](https://www.gengarsworld.com/blog/2022/02/13/Deploy-Jekyll-site-to-Heroku.html) but it does not seem to help me deploy my app successfully on heroku.

I'd be very grateful for any suggestions on what I could be potentially missing

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48457210/jekyll-serve-throws-an-error-on-heroku: "The error seems to be because of a symlinked static_file that is attempting to write to _site/bin/erb after a _site/bin/erb has already been written." Can you exclude the file?

Also [here in a slightly different context](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/2076), the suggestion is to "remove the symlinked directory from version control and add it to gitignore"

Comment: Here's a very old issue on https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/issues/181. It's related to PHP and people ask to create a ticket. Maybe you can use this way to ask for a documentation update :)

Comment: What is the complete output of `git push heroku master`?

Comment: Thank you very much answers @Christian, I'm very grateful for ur kindness & attempt to help me find a solution :). I'll be honest, I'm kinda less inclined to explore the heroku option any further currently because while I was trying to get this hosted for quite a while by trying different options, I was finally able to eventually, get something working on: https://www.netlify.com/ & I wouldn't want to experiment with code after at least find 1 working solution & heroku removing the free dynos plan from Nov 28, 2022 makes me reconsider things. I'm really sorry & I request ur kind understanding.

Comment: No worries, also heard about the removal of free plans yesterday.

Comment: Dear Christian, thank you very much for your understanding :) Please accept my sincere apologies for not being able to respond sooner, was just caught up in working towards a launch over the last week or so. It's a good question about whether or not to have this SO question deleted. If I may, I'd propose leaving this question as is and if people are looking for alternatives to Heroku to deploy Jekyll projects, they'd know that they could try netlify.com in 2022 and that should work well(that's how it was for me). What do you think?

Comment: @boddhisattva GitHub Pages with [custom Build Action](https://github.com/gouravkhunger/portfolio/blob/jekyll/.github/workflows/publish-site.yml) or vercel would also be nice alternatives. idk why but I dont like netlify much. Might be because GitHub is my go to place for all things so I prefer deploying static sites to GitHub pages on the same platform itself.

Comment: Dear @Gourav, firstly please accept my sincere apologies for not being able to respond sooner. Thank you for sharing this with me :) I didn't know about Github related custom build action option or haven't had of Vercel earlier, glad to hear that these alternate options exist in case I may want to switch in the future.